# iOS simulator doesn't update

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I am working on my first iOS app and whenever I change something in Xcode and then build and run, the changes aren't reflected in the simulator. It isn't just code, I've added images as well.

I have both saved and restarted Xcode, and up to a point the changes were reflected in the simulator. But now, no matter what I do, it just shows the old stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that you try Product>Clean and then Product>Run in Xcode.

However, I feel like that is not the real issue, you are probably doing something wrong with the code. Please update your answer with some code samples to show what it is you are changing and how you're changing it

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar issue, what I did is I completely reseted the iOS Simulator. In the menu bar at the top, just go in iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...

This will force a clean build and remove all possible conflicts with the iOS Simulator. If you still have the issue, make sure your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

also try viewing simulator for the other device iPhone/iPad

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to experience this issue personally to find a solution. Check your Target Memberships. If you changed any of them, it might be that! I'm building a watch app and had to change this to make it work again.